# Issues using xeus-sqlite after installing

Tags: sqlite, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

To make a notebook for SQLite I decided to use xeus-sqlite for Jupyter. I followed [the install instructions](https://xeus-sqlite.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/) using Conda.

I ran:

- `conda create -n xeus-sqlite`
- `conda activate xeus-sqlite`
- `conda install xeus-sqlite notebook -c conda-forge`

Not only does xeus-sqlite still not appear in my notebook types (I do not see an xsqlite kernel when I try to create a new notebook), but when I used the console version and entered:

```
%LOAD /Users/alondraperezcortez/Desktop/jobs_copy.db
```

I get following error:

> UsageError: Line magic function `%LOAD` not found.

I restarted my computer and reloaded both in a fresh terminal. I also tried [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/xeus-sqlite/) to install xeus with no luck. I am on MacBook Pro 2019 2.4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5 running macOS Ventura 13.0 (22A380).